# How can I run two python programs simultaneously that both require user-inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, simultaneous

I have two programs that I am trying to run with one python program. There is an ATP automated test procedure python program and a Thermocouple data recording program. I'm trying to run both programs at the same time with a separate program. Both of those programs require inputs like:

- string names of components thermocouples are attached to
- how many loops to run for duration of program
- name of the csv file that you would like to create and write data to
- etc.

I want to run them simultaneously because it would be much easier if I could have a top level program that takes one or two inputs from me and then uses that to generate string names for csv file names and the loops needed and so on.

I've tried implementing the thermocouple data code into the ATP file but anytime I create the file in one function and then write to it in another (which I need to do) it ends up jeopardizing the functionality of the ATP file.

I found a solution like below listed but it didn't seem to work. I tried something way more basic than what it needed to be such as my programs (i have to have FPGAs, thermocouples and power supplies hooked up just to try the code). If I can make it work for a simple program that requires some inputs, I should be able to make it work for a much larger program.

```
import subprocess
import multiprocessing

def main():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        files = ["___pathway here___\yeswow.py","___pathway here___\nowow.py"]
        for i in files:
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
            p.start()
main()
```

I ended up getting some error code like this which I didn't really understand.

```
(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape (<unknown>, line 14)pylint(syntax-error)
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping your backslashes? e.g. doing `'\\'` instead of `'\'` in your file strings?

Comment: Good idea! I didn't even think of that. I just tried and now I'm getting some different errors haha. I'm being told by the terminal that there is a TypeError: main() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.